# Implementing JQuery Scrollbox - amending the function - not sure how to do it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scripting

I'm working with a blog and I wanted to place a JQuery scroll bar into my div box for the main content area. I'm kind of new to JS but I think I missed something. The devs provided a script but I don't believe its correct. Just a side note: all the libraries are loaded before the script so I don't believe that's where the problem is. Here is what I current have (MINUS all the Sql crap):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="../css/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="BKlayer2">
    <img src="../Images/BKlayer2.png" />
        <div class="InnerContent1">
          <img src="../Images/innerContent1.png" />
</div>
        <div class="innerContent2">
            <img src="../Images/innerContent2.png" />
    </div>
        <div class="Feedback">
          <img src="../Images/Feedblockbk.png" />
    </div>

<div id="blog_Posts">
<?php do { ?> Updated on: <?php echo $row_displayBehaviors['formatted']; ?><br />
      <br />
  <?php echo $row_displayBehaviors['title']; ?>
      <br />
      <br />
      <?php echo $row_displayBehaviors['blog_entry']; ?>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <?php } while ($row_displayBehaviors = mysql_fetch_assoc($displayBehaviors)); ?>
</div>
<?php
mysql_free_result($getArchives);

mysql_free_result($displayBehaviors);
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".blog_Posts").mCustomScrollbar();
                theme:"light"
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed .content to .blog_Posts because that's the div box I'm trying to apply this too. I checked all other css and additional info to make sure .content was not referenced anywhere else.

After uploading scripts and all other relevant information to my server, I checked in firebug to find out the problem.

Now firebug is giving me this error:

```
    TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$(".blog_Posts").mCustomScrollbar();
```

I think firebug said it better than I could. I didn't see a function defined here. I'm not exactly sure what the function would be if it has to be included.

Comment: please show us what scripts you are loading and in what order

Comment: I edited to add in all the code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you haven't included the jQuery plugin script.

`mCustomScrollbar` is not a part of jQuery, you'll need to reference the plugin.

This sounds like the plugin you are talking about, include the script reference from there:
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just if anyone wants to know:

I did it by working backwards on the demo script and figuring it out. Basically what I didn't do was have the CSS lined up and I also didn't have the scripts in the correct directories.

As for the proper script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/minified/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<!-- custom scrollbars plugin -->
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
$(".body,.content").mCustomScrollbar({
scrollButtons:{
enable:true
}
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

basically I added in the .body in and changed .content so it corresponded to my main styles sheet. You really don't need any css on your page other than this:

```
<style>
body>.mCustomScrollBox>.mCSB_scrollTools{top:2%; height:96%;}
</style>
```

That's the key I was missing.